# Repositioning the content on main page after response from ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, html

On my index.php I have following html structure

```
<input type="text"  class="url" id="url" name="url" contenteditable="true"  style=" text-align: left; height: 30px; width:422px; " placeholder="Enter URL ..." onfocus='display();' /></input> //Text box
<div id = "myDiv"> // Div which holds response from ajax call
<input type="submit" class="button" onclick="GetSentiment()" id="GetSentiment" value="Get Sentiment" style="display:none;"/> //Button which call function to perform action
```

and ajax call:

```
function GetSentiment()
        {
  .....
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                    {                       document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }
                }
                xmlhttp.open("POST","data.php",true); ...
```

data.php contains this sort of result that is here :http://jsfiddle.net/karimkhan/xftr5/

Initially Button is just below the text box.

After button click and action performed, response coming from data.php file place just below the textbox.

So the button gets hidden. Rather I want it to place below the response of data.php. i.e. below `myDiv`

Comment: If you have `jQuery` why not use `$("myDiv").load()`?

Comment: How is your `div` styled and is that closed like `<div id = "myDiv">...</div>` ?

Comment: @RCV: it has no stlye and yes its closed like you showed!

Comment: @FritsvanCampen: sorry no jquery

Comment: @Karimkhan then why do you have the jQuery tag?

Comment: @FritsvanCampen: I have just ajax. where is jquery?

Comment: You tagged this question as jquery, did you mean javascript instead?

Comment: @FritsvanCampen: Oh sorry, I meant JS